# Question on CSS hover/mouseover in iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ipad, mobile-safari

Imagine there are 5 sublinks (having class `searchBySub`) and 5 corresponding buttons on a page..

Now these 5 sublinks have following clas definitions

```
#leftNav .searchBySub {...}
#leftNav  a.searchBySub:hover {...}
#leftNav  a.searchBySubClick {...}
```

Now I am testing this page on the iPad.
Any of the 5 sublinks can be clicked which changes it CSS (offcourse shows the clicked link as selected color)

Also if I click on any of the corresponding button, it should show me the corresponding link with selected color...I am doing this via a click event on this button click;

```
$(".button1").live("click",function(){
            $("link1").click(); //This is not exact code (but written dynamically...anyways it simulates the first link click)
        });
```

Just one more thing, I am unable to show the exact code as the content gets refreshed via an AJAX call on each link/button click, which is why I have used the jQuery.live() for the bindings...

Now my issue is , on the iPAD, when I simulate the click via the button click, on let's say Button2, while link1 is selected currently, it will correctly show link2 as selected color....
But for some reasons, it is showing link1 with hover state during this simulated click...I have no idea whatsoever why this is happening..

Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to capture and take action on the `touchstart` event.  For mobile devices without mice, you get a series of events when someone taps on the screen:

- `touchstart`
- `touchend`
- `mousedown`
- `mouseup`
- `click`

The `mouse*` events don't happen until after `touchend`, which may not be the behavior you want.  Check out [Apple's mobile Safari event docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html) for more info:

Comment: Actually I have added live() handlers for touchstart, click, mouseover...But still does not work...Essentially what I want is to remove the :hover state from the link when the button is clicked...

Comment: The concept of "hover" doesn't translate well to touch devices.  There is no hover.  With a mouse, there's a clear delineation between when the mouse pointer is over something and when you've engaged the mouse button.  With touch devices, there's no such distinction.  You're either touching the device or you're not.  So my recommendation is to get away from using :hover in CSS, and instead, use events that best match what you want to achieve, whether that's touchstart, mousedown, click, etc.

Comment: Well I am completely aware there is no hover concept on iPad....But I am trying to implement this thing on an existing desktop web app (same is used for ipad) and for some reason it does apply the :hover state that is defined in the CSS...I am looking for someway to override this...Please read my question carefully and you'll come to know what I am looking for exactly...

Comment: If you are using `touchstart` you should cancel your action if you have any `touchmove` before `touchend`, to prevent accidental trigger when the user is just scrolling the page.